# php Get level array from Array Tree

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I Have the next array:
Array
(
    [1000] => Array
        (
            [pv] => 81
        )

```
[1101] => Array
    (
        [1102] => Array
            (
                [pv] => 33
            )

        [1103] => Array
            (
                [pv] => 15
            )

        [pv] => 72
    )
```

)
I want to make new array from this like this:

```
Array(
[1000] => Array(['generation'] => 1, ['pv'] => 81)
[1101] => Array(['generation'] => 1, ['pv'] => 72)
[1102] => Array(['generation'] => 2, ['pv'] => 33)
[1103] => Array(['generation'] => 2, ['pv'] => 15)
)
```

Generation is a level of array's deep. There are a lot of levels.
Thanks.

Comment: By mistake you've posted the same question twice. Please delete this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php Get level array from Array Tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784892/php-get-level-array-from-array-tree)

Comment: you asked 4! very similar questions yesterday. haven't you learned anything from that solutions? this is just a tiny modification of the other ones. i don't want to be mean, but have you even tried to do this yourself - and, if you have, could you please post your code so we can teach you what's wrong with it?

Comment: It is different problems. I have some problems with arrays and recursion. Please help. Duplicate quastion has been deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be creative...

```
function coffee($elm, $cur_key=NULL, $level=0, &$push_arr=NULL){
   if(!is_array($push_arr)) $pusH_arr = array();
   $level++;
   foreach($elm as $key=>$val){
      if($key == 'pv'){
         $push_arr[$cur_key] = array(
             'generation' => $level,
             'pv' => $val
         );
      }
      else if(is_array($val)){
         coffee($val, $key, $level, $push_arr);
      }
      else{
         // unexpected value
      }
   }
   return $push_arr;
}
// Usage:
$normalised_array = coffee($array_from_your_question);
```